# Improving Performance and Scalability of Simple DataFrame Operations

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe, scalability

I'm analyzing some transaction data for a colleague's car exchange platform. I have made this program to do some operations on the data but I'm wondering if I can improve the performance (time and space requirements) as he will be looking at a lot of data.

The program reads in specification data (size, color etc) on the submitted cars for the exchange (cars.csv), the transaction data (trans.csv) and a JSON file containing exchange rules. The rules consist of physical car specification rules (cars must be certain size and not a certain color) and transaction rules (transactions for cars that didn't pass specification test are ignored and each transaction is limited to a max value)

In general, the program should do the following:

- Create a dateframe of submitted car spec data
- Filter cars based off exchange rules (carsAllowed)
- Create a dataframe of transaction data
- Filter transaction of cars not in carsAllowed and set a maximum on transaction value
- Group transactions by color and calculate total value

Below is a simple outline of the program and it works fine. However, I'm wondering if you guys see any performance bottlenecks (example, for very large amounts of car specification or transaction data)

Thanks

```
import pandas as pd

# read in car data and exchange rules
cars = pd.read_csv("cars.csv")
rules = pd.read_json("rules.json")


# combine car rules into test 
test = ((cars["Size"] == rules["CarSpecs"][0]["AllowedSize"][0]) \
| (cars["Size"] == rules["CarSpecs"][0]["AllowedSize"][1])) \
& (cars["Color"] != rules["CarSpecs"][1]["ForbiddenColor"][0])

# filter cars with test
carsAllowed = cars[test]

# read exchange transaction data
transactions = pd.read_csv("transac.csv")

# apply exchange transaction rules(i.e. transaction value cannot be above some max value and carId from transaction should be in dataframe carsAllowed)
transactions = transactions[transactions["CarId"].isin(carsAllowed["CarId"])]
transactions["transVal"] = transactions["transVal"].apply(lambda transVal: rules["MaxTransVal"][0] if transVal>=rules["MaxTransVal"][0] else transVal)

# finally, group transactions by car colors and calculate total transaction value for each

# first take car color information from carsAllowed as it is not included in transaction data 
transactions["Color"] = transactions["CarId"].apply(lambda carId: carsAllowed[carsAllowed["CarId"] == carId]["Color"].item())
transactions.groupby("Color")["transVal"].sum()
```

Comment: You might want to post this to the [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead. [Stack Overflow is for problems with code that isn’t working, while Code Review is for making already-working code better](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211790/394238).

Comment: @jschoi thank you, I'll do that.